# Expand rows from existing data in SQL

Tags: sql, data-manipulation

I have a table that looks like this:

```
User   HasPermA   HasPermB   HasPermC
---------------------------------------
Joe    True       False      True
Sally  True       True       True
```

And I need to transform it into the following format using SQL:

```
User   PermissionType
-----------------------
Joe          A
Joe          C
Sally        A
Sally        B
Sally        C
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Any particular dialect of SQL you're looking to use? That second example is how your data should be stored in the first place, so I hope you can do this as part of fixing your schema.

Comment: @tadman - Almost funny to see an exact opposite of the pivot question (which has to be the #1 asked SQL question by a wide margin), isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use UNION ALL:

```
select *
from
(
    select user
        , case when HasPermA is true then 'A' else null end as PermissionType
    from table

    union all

    select user
        , case when HasPermB is true then 'B' else null end as PermissionType
    from table

    union all

    select user
        , case when HasPermC is true then 'C' else null end as PermissionType
    from table
) sub
where sub.PermissionType is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is `union all`, which I would phrase as:

```
select user, 'A' as PermissionType from t where HasPermA union all
select user, 'B' from t where HasPermB union all
select user, 'C' from t where HasPermC ;
```

This assumes that your dialect of SQL understands boolean variables.  You might need something like `HasPermA = 'true'`.

Several dialects of SQL support lateral joins -- using either the `lateral` keyword or the `apply` keyword (or both).  If so, I like:

```
select t.user, v.PermissionType
from t outer apply
     (value ('A', HasPermA), ('B', HasPermA), ('C', HasPermA)) v(PermissionType, hasPerm)
where hasPerm;
```

Using a lateral join (or `unpivot` query) has the advantage of only scanning the table once.